# How to generate a random number 1 and 5 based on user input ,If player guesses it right print correct if false print wrong

Tags: python

I don't know how to print how the user will guess it and how to print if the users correct or incorrect

I tried to find a youtube video but could not find any

```
guees=input("guees a number bettwen 1 and 5:")
print(random.rarange(0 , 5))
```

Comment: Is that random number an integer between 1 and 5 (inclusive?) or is it ANY number between 1 and 5 (inclusive?)?

Comment: it's any number between 1 and 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

guess = input('Guess a number: ')
print('correct' if guess == random.uniform(1,5) else 'wrong')
```

Please refer to the document about `random.uniform` here:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.uniform

In this specific case I doubt you'll have any "correct" output because what's generated is a floating number.

Perhaps generating a random integer between 1 and 5 makes more sense:

```
print('correct' if guess == random.randint(1,5) else 'wrong')
```

Comment: so print('correct' if guess == random.randint(1,5) else 'wrong') does this let the user have a correct outpout

Comment: @PranavBedi to be precise - there will be 6 possibilities of outputs using `random.randint` so it give you better chance to guess correctly